# set theory - trivial question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have a set $\Omega = \{ \{1 \},\{2\} \}$ is it true that $\{1,2\}$ belongs to $\Omega$?
I guess it is true because $\{a \}  \cup \{b \} = \{a,b\}$. Then what is confusing me is if I have a power set $P(\Omega ) = \{ \emptyset ,\{ 1\} ,\{ 2\} ,\{ 1,2\} \} $ why do I need to have explicitly listed $\{1,2\}$ as a particular element of $\Omega$ when it is already ensured by the presence of the sets $\{ 1\} ,\{ 2\}$.

Comment: But $\{a,b\} \ne \{\{a\},\{b\}\}$.

Comment: Also you made a mistake $\mathcal P(\Omega ) \neq \{ \emptyset ,\{ 1\} ,\{ 2\} ,\{ 1,2\} \},$ the correct expression is $\mathcal P(\Omega)=\big\{\emptyset,\{\{1\}\},\{\{2\}\},\{\{1\},\{2\}\}\big\}.$

Comment: If I have $\{ 1,2\}  = \{ 1\}  \cup \{ 2\} $ can't I use a similar principle to $\{ \{ 1\} ,\{ 2\} \} $? Then I should get $\{ \{ 1\} ,\{ 2\} \}  = \{ \{ 1\}  \cup \{ 2\} \}  = \{ \{ 1,2\} \}$

Comment: @Fragile But $\{1\}\cup\{2\}=\{1,2\}\neq\{1\},\{2\}.$

Comment: I think the mistake I made was the following: $\{ \{ 1\} ,\{ 2\} \}  = \{ \{ 1\} \}  \cup \{ \{ 2\} \} $ but $\{ \{ 1\} ,\{ 2\} \}  \ne \{ \{ 1\}  \cup \{ 2\} \} $, which is what I assumed above. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

If $\Omega=\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$, then $\Omega$ contains only two elements: $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$.  Since $\{1\}\ne\{1,2\}$ and $\{2\}\ne\{1,2\}$, then  $\{1,2\}$ is not an element of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 2):

Each "subset" is a element of $\Omega$, i.e, $\Omega$ is a set of sets, then

$P(\Omega) = \{\emptyset,\{\{1\}\} ,\{\{2\}\} , \Omega \}$

Comment: Yes ! thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

Belonging relation is not transtive, that is, you can have that $x\in X$ and $X\in\mathcal X$ but $x\notin\mathcal X$.

For example, $1\notin\{\{1\}\}$

Comment: This is not quite the issue here, but it was the issue on a question yesterday.